# Java JTextField stopping GUI

Tags: java, jframe

Currently my code looks like this

```
public Frame(String title, Integer x, Integer y)
{
    gui = new JFrame(title);

    // Give style to the GUI

    this.Style(x, y);

    // Build our GUI

    new Builder(gui);
}

public void Style(Integer width, Integer height)
{
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setResizable(false);
    gui.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    gui.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 4));
}
```

Builder.java

```
public class Builder 
{
    public Builder(JFrame frame)
    {
        Build gui = new Build(frame);
        JTextField input = gui.buildInput("aaaaa");
        JButton button1 = gui.buildButton("aaa");
        JButton button21 = gui.buildButton("aaa");
    }
}
```

Build.java

```
public class Build 
{
    private JFrame frame;

    public Build(JFrame frame)
    {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public JButton buildButton(String text)
    {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        frame.add(button);

        return button;
    }

    public JTextField buildInput(String text)
    {
        JTextField textArea = new JTextField(text);
        frame.add(textArea);

        return textArea;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except when I try to add a JTextField, if I do it the JTextField doesnt appear and the rest of the GUI elements dissapear, for example I try the following on my Builder class

```
   Build gui = new Build(frame);
   //JTextField input = gui.buildInput("aaaaa");
   JButton button1 = gui.buildButton("aaa");
   JButton button21 = gui.buildButton("aaa");
```

Works and displays 2 buttons on my frame but I un-comment the JTextField input the GUI buttons wont show same as the TextField.

Comment: Try adding a LayoutManager to the JFrame

Comment: Im currently using a GridLayout

Comment: How are you sizing your `JFrame`?

Comment: gui.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));

Comment: `Im currently using a GridLayout` - not based on the code you posted. It looks to me like you are trying to add multiple components to the CENTER of the BorderLayout of the frame. Only the last component added will be displayed. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem if you need more help. I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples that will help you better structure your code.

Comment: If I add 2 buttons they work great but trying to add a TextField breaks my code / Code updated

Comment: What happens if you use the constructor [`JTextField(String text, int columns)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with non-zero value for `columns`? Could be an issue with it defaulting to 0 columns with the current constructor.

Comment: Tried textArea.setColumns(10); but nothing displayed.

Comment: Making the GridLayout(5, 4) doesn't make sense. You should NOT be making the frame visible BEFORE you add components to the frame. The code is way too complicated for such a simple task. There is no need for all the classes you created. Read the tutorial and look at the examples for a much simpler approach. Finally you still haven't posted a `SSCCE` which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Okey, making the GUI visible the last line worked and now the Input field is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tracked down any official documentation regarding your issue, but the problem appears to be that your frame is not invalidating and re-validating itself when you add the components to it. I was able to resolve this two different ways.

1. Move your call for `frame.setVisible(true)` to *after* you have built the GUI. This will force the frame to re-validate its layout before displaying.
2. Make a call to `frame.validate()` *after* building the GUI, which also solves the problem.

Placing either of these in the final line of your `Builder` constructor worked fine for me in both cases.

Ordinarily, adding components to another component *should* force a re-validation, but for some reason this is not happening. However, I generally try to add all my components to my frames before making them visible anyways, and might be a good practice to get into.

**Edit:** I found this in the API documentation for the [`add(Component comp)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) method in `java.awt.Containter` (emphasis mine):

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy. *If the container has already been displayed*, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to display the added component.

Thus, if the component is already visible, it must be validated. Calling `setVisible(true)` will cause a validation, and is why if it is called after adding everything fixes the problem.

Comment: `Ordinarily, adding components to another component should force a re-validation,` - It is the programs responsibility to invoke revalidate() and repaint() when you add components to a visible GUI. You add components BEFORE you invoke pack() or setVisible() on the frames.